# When running a TestCafe test file via a git pre-commit hook, how can I return a boolean value whether any test has failed?

Tags: git, testing, automated-tests, sh, testcafe

Right now I'm just triggering the tests to run with `testcafe chrome general-tests.js`. But I need to get back a boolean value whether or not any tests have failed so I can create a condition. If a fail is detected, then `exit 1` will stop the commit.

Is there a testcafe command of flag that can be used for this? Or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`testcafe` returns an exit code when there's a failure, so what you're asking for should work out of the box.

I was able to get back an exit code of 1 for the following:

- Test failures
- Using a browser it couldn't find
- Using a test it couldn't find

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am purposely failing one of the tests and it's still making the commit. So I wasn't sure if there is a flag for the command that I can't find yet. Or do I need more in my hook file rather than just `testcafe chrome general-test.js`

Comment: I'm not sure how your hooks are set up. I just installed the [pre-commit npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pre-commit) and followed the instructions there. I have one script command for running testcafe, and point to that script command in the pre-commit config. When testcafe failed, so did the git commit! It worked on the first try, so hopefully you just have a hook issue.

Comment: Thank you! The pre-commit npm package worked for me.